# How do I remove File Extensions from an HTML webpage usual way not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

htaccess file and my code doesn't remove .HTML here is the code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Your code looks ok to me,what is the URL you are hitting in browser?

Comment: localhost:8000/page is the page from localhost:8000/page.html

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 am I doing something wrong?

Comment: So you are hitting `http:localhost:80/page` which you want to serve by page.html from backend right? Kindly confirm once. If that is the case then what's the error you getting?

Comment: Yes that is right but I don't see any way to view any errors

Comment: Ok let's do one test if your htaccess is enabled or not, add this line `-----------` in your htaccess file and then save it and try hitting any URL if you getting 500 internal errors then it means htaccess working else htaccess is NOT ENABLED, test it once and let me know how it goes then.

Comment: No Error 500 internal Poping Up

Comment: Ok it means your htaccess is enabled.

Comment: is it cause im hosting it on php -S localhost:8000

Comment: That was because you added the `------` remove that now from htaccess file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your shown samples could you please try following once. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```